Wix v5 Bootstrapper Application Localization Bug
I am trying to localize a bootstrapper that I am building with Wix v5. I need my bootstrapper to detect the system language and display the UI strings in the appropriate language. I found a solution here that works how I want it to. I have added my translations to the WXL files, and then added those files as payloads like so:
    <BootstrapperApplication>
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        Theme="rtfLicense"/>
      <Payload Name="2058\thm.wxl" SourceFile="2058\thm.wxl"/>
      <Payload Name="3084\thm.wxl" SourceFile="3084\thm.wxl"/>
    </BootstrapperApplication>

This method works when I compile the .exe and run the bootstrapper on my machine with the display language set to one of the two supported languages. However, when I try to uninstall or modify the package from the Apps & Features or Programs in the Control Panel, the UI reverts to English. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? How do I get the uninstall dialogs to translate properly?

What do the uninstall log files say?

For me the uninstall dialogs are localized correctly with WiX v5. I have a similar bootstrapper configuration, with some small differences. I don't know if they are significant, but you  might give it a try. WixStandardBootstrapperApplication attribute LocalizationFile="1033\thm.wxl" (English) and Payload attribute Compressed="yes". I've also included a payload for the english thm.wxl.

@RobMensching, where are the uninstall logs written? I do not see them in the default location with the install logs.

@zett42 This did not solve it for me.
Interestingly, when I rerun the .exe after installing the bundle, I get the correct repair/uninstall UI with the translations. They do not appear in the proper language when I run the repair/uninstall process from the Apps or Control Panel menu.

Logs are written to %TEMP% by default.

@RobMensching it doesn't appear that logs are getting written when I uninstall the bundle.
